# DownloadFileAsync in loop with CompletedEvent gets only the last file

Tags: c#

I'm getting several file links from a file into a loop statement and for each link , I have to download the file , when the download was completed I have to do something with each file.

Here is my code,

```
      foreach(//condition ) {
            Descarcare = new WebClient();
                                Descarcare.DownloadProgressChanged += Descarcare_DownloadProgressChanged;
                                Descarcare.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(nod.SelectSingleNode("DownloadLink").InnerText), Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()+);
                                Descarcare.DownloadFileCompleted +=Descarcare_DownloadFileCompleted;
}

    void Descarcare_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       //extract the file
    }
```

But somehow , the webclient downloads the files but the DownloadFileCompleted event fires only for the last downloaded file instead of doing it for each file.

What can cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `WebClient` in every iteration of your `foreach`-loop. The best approach is to create a [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7977ey2c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with all files and start a new download in each DownloadFileCompleted until you got all the files you want.

```
var _downloadQueue = new Queue<Uri>();
var _webClient = new WebClient();

//in your constructor:
_webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += Descarcare_DownloadProgressChanged;
_webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += Descarcare_DownloadFileCompleted;

private void Foo()
{
    //...

    foreach(/* condition */) 
    {
        _downloadQueue.Enqueue(
            new Uri(nod.SelectSingleNode("DownloadLink").InnerText)
        );                                    
    }

    DownloadNext();
}

private void DownloadNext()
{
    if(_downloadQeue.Count> 0)
    {
        _webClient.DownloadFileAsync(
            _downloadQueue.Dequeue(), Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
        );
    }
}

void Descarcare_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    DownloadNext();

    //extract the file
    //...
}
```

Comment: Umm..yea, I'm getting : WebClient does not support concurrent I/O Operations exception

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that. I will update my example.